# Jenkins Pipeline and Promotions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When having build job with implemented promotion cycle, i.e. Dev->QA->Performance->Production.

What will be the **correct** way to migrate this cycle into pipeline? it looks rather clean\structured to call each of the above mentioned jobs, Yet, How can I query the build ID (to be able to call the deployment job)? Or I have have totally misunderstood the pipeline concept?

Comment: How many jobs do you have today ? One job for each of your step Dev/QA/Performance/Production ? Only one job for each part and an external deploy job ? It would help if you could explain how your actual jobs are organized and which job call each other :)

Comment: There are dozens of such cycles

Answer (score 0):

It is better to call each build in separate pipeline stages. Something like this:

```java
stage "Dev"
node{
       build job: 'Dev', parameters:
       [
         [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param', value: "param"],
       ];
    }
stage "QA"
node{
    build job: 'QA'
}

etc...
```

To cycle this process you ca use retry option or endless cycle in Groovy

Answer (score 0):

You might consider multiple solutions :

### Trigger each job sequentially

Just call each job sequentially using `build` step :

```java
node() {
  stage "Dev"
  build job: 'Dev'

  stage "QA"
  build job: 'QA'

  // Your other promotion cycles...
}
```

It is easy to use and will probably be already compliant with your actual solution, but I'm not a big fan of this solution because the actual output of your pipeline stages (Dev, QA, etc.) will really be in the dedicated job (Dev job, QA job) instead of being directly inside your pipeline. Your pipeline will be an empty shell just calling other jobs...

### Call pipelines functions instead of jobs

Define a pipeline function for each of your promotion cycle (preferably in an external file) and then call each function sequentially. Example :

```java
node {
  git 'http://urlToYourGit/projectContainingYourFunctions'
  cycles = load 'promotions-cycles.groovy'

  stage "Dev"
  cycles.dev()

  stage "QA"
  cycles.qa()

  // Your other promotion cycles calls...
}
```

The biggest advantages is that your promotions cycles code is commited in your Git repository and that all your stages output is actually a part of your pipeline output, which is great for easy debugging.
Plus you can easily apply conditions based on the success/failure of your functions (e.g. if your QA stage fails you don't want to go any further).

Note that both solutions should allow you to launch your promotions cycles in parallel if needed and to pass parameters to either your jobs or functions.